# Boolean value does not reflect everywhere with ng-model; verified with Batarang and using controller-as

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to understand watchers, but I've come across a bit of a weird problem.

I have code like this:

**HTML**

```
<div ng-app='dummyApp'>
  <div ng-controller="SampleController as sample">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="sample.toggleValue" />
    <p ng-model="sample.toggleValue"></p>
    <textarea ng-model = "sample.toggleValue"></textarea>
    <p ng-model="sample.text"></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
(function() {
    angular.module('dummyApp', []);
    angular.module('dummyApp')
        .controller('SampleController', SampleController);

    function SampleController($scope) {
        var vm = this;

        vm.text = "";


        $scope.$watch('sample.toggleValue', function(newVal, oldVal) {

            console.log({newval: newVal, old: oldVal});
            vm.text = vm.text + ";";
        });

    }
})();
```

The `console.log` works correctly, and shows the values as they are changed in the console. But neither the value of `toggleValue` nor the value of `text` show up in the browser; both the `<p>`s remain empty(Actually, I want to have a value by default in the p tags which is not related to the variable in the ng-model(such as <unknown>).). I've checked their classes, and they're `ng-pristine`, `ng-untouched` and `ng-empty`.

However, the `<textarea>` shows the `true/false` value as expected.

I'm not using $scope anywhere in the DOM, so I don't think this is an issue with inheritance.
I've also checked the scope with Batarang.

I'm at a loss here.

P.S. Here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/6bud04er/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no text in the `p` tags, thats the reason they are not visible. Do not use [**ng-model**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel) for `p` tags, that is not the purpose of it. `ngModel` binds an `input` to the ModelController. If you want the value to be added to `<p>` tags, use **[ng-bind](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBind)** directive or use `{{ expression }}` syntax of angular as shown below.

```js
(function() {
    angular.module('dummyApp', []);
    angular.module('dummyApp')
        .controller('SampleController', SampleController);

    function SampleController($scope) {
        var vm = this;

        vm.text = "";

        $scope.default = "default string";
        $scope.$watch('sample.toggleValue', function(newVal, oldVal) {

            console.log({newval: newVal, old: oldVal});
            //vm.text += vm.text + ";";
        });

    }
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app='dummyApp'>
  <div ng-controller="SampleController as sample">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="sample.toggleValue" />
    <textarea ng-model = "sample.text"></textarea>
    <p ng-hide="sample.toggleValue">toggle is false</p>
    <p>{{default}}</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Okay, I'll use `ng-bind`. I wanted to have a value by default in the p tags which was not related to the variable in the ng-model(such as <unknown>).

Comment: If you want a normal `p` tag with a drafult value, define a `$scope.default` in the controller and bind it to p tag using ng-bind

Answer (score 0):

To show a boolean value just remove ng-model in **p** tag and use  `<p>{{ sample.toggleValue }}</p>`